# How safe is storing a cryptographic hash of sensitive information?

Tags: hash, cryptography, bcrypt, pii

Trying to find a way to reduce duplicate contact entries in a system.  Names, email addresses, home addresses, and phone numbers can change, so those aren't 100% unique identifiers.

However, date of birth and SSN do not change.  I'm thinking about storing a combination of `date_of_birth-ssn` as a cryptographic hash to uniquely identify a contact and merge duplicates.

My understanding is that it's mathematically "impossible" to reverse the hash thus it's "safe" to store the `ssn` in this fashion.

I know the safest way is not to store anything.  However, I'm not sure what other info I can use to uniquely identify a person.

Is there a better solution to uniquely identifying people that wouldn't utilize sensitive info like a `ssn`?

Answer (score 2):

This is decidedly **not** safe.

In general you can't reverse a hash. If I has large blobs of random data and give you the hash, you cannot get back the blob. That is not what you are proposing.

With 365 days a year and everyone being under 100 years old, there are only about 36500 possible DoBs (OK, some people are over 100, but not your contacts - the actual number of possible DoBs is probably around 20,000).  SSN is 9 digits, so only 1,000,000,000 possible values (actually a lot less).

All told there are 20,000,000,000,000 possible combinations. Sound like a lot? It's not. This laptop that I'm using can do over 11 million hashes per second per core. It can test all possible combinations in 1,707,026 seconds or 19 days. With one 4-year-old laptop core. A powerful server with 20 cores that costs a few thousands of dollars (no specialized hardware) can prepare this table in hours. And then I can reverse not the hash function, but the subset of outputs that you might see.

Comment: Interestingly SSN have a pattern that can reduce the possibilities. The first three digits indicate the geographic region of issue but my SSS falls into the group: "Not Issued" so I guess I don't exist .

Comment: @synp, thanks for the detailed response.  I would agree with your assessment that it's not a good solution and I shouldn't use it.  I would be using BCrypt for the actual algorithm, and that adds a salt to the value before encrypting it, which helps a little but still may not make it "takes the age of the universe to crack" kind of safe.  Instead of storing any information, I guess I'm left with a check on the first/last names and DoB, and will just deal with the one-off exceptions where names change when they arise.